# Magento 2 : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch()

Tags: magento2

I get this error in a block that I am developing to get current category. any ideas?

```
class CurrentCategory extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
)
{
    $this->_registry = $registry;
}

public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
}
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on 
>     null in 
>    /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:652

Comment: If you have found an answer please use arrows/checkmark to upvote/accept an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
class CurrentCategory extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_registry = $registry;
}

public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
}
```

**run upgrade, compile and deploy command and clear cache**

Comment: Thanks! but... same error :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply inherit (or use, if you don't want to add functionality) from `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View` instead of `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` to get access to the `getCurrentCategory()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser but... same result :)

Answer (score 0):

You constructor has to match the parent one ... please try this:

```
public function __construct
(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_registry = $registry;
}
```